# Xamarin : Loading resources via GetManifestResourceStream

Tags: opengl-es, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am working on a Xamarin forms project to use OpenGL/OpenTK.  I am trying to load a shader using GetManifestResourceStream.  Whatever I do I get null

code is being run from .Shared project, shaders are in .ios / .Android resources directory

```
string prefix;

#if __IOS__ 
prefix = "OpenGLTesting.iOS.";
#endif
#if __ANDROID__
prefix = "OpenGLTesting.Droid.";
#endif

var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo ().Assembly;
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream (prefix + shaderName + ".glsl");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add some debugging code, like calling `assembly.GetManifestResourceNames ();` so make sure you have both the right name and that it was embedded in your assembly.